# Registry.CurrentUser is null

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I am using the following property to set/read registry values in my code. However, in the line:

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
```

regKey is null. This is happening only in a few machines. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe permissions issue - logged in user running your application might not have permission to read the registry thus it returns null? If running on Windows 7, try asking the user to run the application as Administrator (right click -> Run As Administrator) and see if this helps.

Comment: No, its Windows Xp, And i have also tried impersonating as Admin user. Still got the error.

Comment: You said it's happening in "few machines" - what machines? All XP? Maybe 64 bit issue? We need to find something common to all those machines to have a good lead.

Comment: It would seem strange if the current user (!) cannot access the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive. A lot of (even non-admin) applications would not work. Looking with reflector, it seems that `CurrentUser` is directly initialized by a `new`-instruction and thus there is little that can happen for it to be `null`. An exception somewhere from a static ctor would be more likely.

Answer (score 0):

```
RegistryKey regRPP = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Softech\FaceReader");
```

//this is the path it will create

```
regRPP.SetValue("FaceReaderURL", "http://localhost/pnm/v4_spp/");
```

Comment: If `Registry.CurrentUser` is really `null` (as the OP said) the first statement will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Funnily, it did not throw exception and it worked. Surprising!

Comment: it'll automatically creates that registry path