# Accessing Registry Keys from .dll in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, registry, electron

The environment I'm using might sound a bit messed up, so I will try to explain it at best.
I'm doing some experimental things with Electron. Right now, I have a simple .dll written in C# with using .NET Standard 2.0 as the base. On Electron's side, I'm using electron-edge-js, which, I think, works fine because I'm able to communicate with both of them.

So basic process goes like this, 
I'm building my C# code to get my .dll's (I'm also adding reference dlls as well). Putting them into the same folder with Electron project. Starting the project to see how they did.

The problem lies at .dll's code. I'm using the following simple code,

```
 public string RegisterUser(string username, string userkey) {
            try {
                RegistryKey key;
                if (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser == null) return "Current user is null";
                key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Test\TestFunctions");
                if (key == null) return "Key is null";
                key.SetValue("uid", username);
                key.SetValue("upsw", userkey);
                key.Close();
                return "Done";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.ToString();
            }
        }
```

However, whenever I call this method, it always returns "Current user is null" no matter what. I tried building my .exe and running it as administrator as well. I checked the privileges in Regedit as well. They all seem fine. I'm having a kinda hard time for such an *easy* code. A little help would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895621/registry-currentuser-is-null). I can't mark it as duplicate, but the OP has commented on the answer that it seems to work despite being null. If that works for you, Please upvote that answer and we.can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Unrelated tip: `RegistryKey` is `IDisposable` so should be in a `using` block.

Comment: Sadly, I already checked that and It didn't work at all. Frankly, that thread isn't giving much information about the cause or ways to resolve that issue. It looks like it just magically resolved with no reason. I'm suspecting that my problem is more related to _permissions_ or Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll, but I don't know where to look exactly. I hope someone can clear that up for me.

Comment: OK. Do the other keys behave the same? E.g. Does LocalMachine work properly?

Comment: No, they don't work. But I guess It's not normal to access LocalMachine _just like that_ anywany. As far as I understand from other peoples' past experiences, you need to do some more stuff for accessing LocalMachine(Granting more privileges etc)  
I also tried to open an existing sub key as well, not working too. It's always throwing null excepting when I try to access anything after Registry.CurrentUser

Comment: Just modify the registry from Electron: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-registry Getting c# involved is just complicating everything

Comment: @Tim I actually don't want to give up from my design just because it gets complicated. I know using that package would save me from a lot of headaches but it's not finding a solution to this problem but only offers a workaround. I'm assuming that this problem is occurring because Nodejs runs with some sorta low privileges so it's not able to access registry keys. Could that be the problem?